# Cannot resize Facebook Comments and some other text in Chrome

Tags: css, facebook, google-chrome, text, resize

Thanks in advance for your help! I have noticed that some text will not resize when I browse with Chrome, including embedded Facebook Comments, the Mailchimp Application, and other text that I've come across. For an example, view [this page of Inc.com](http://www.inc.com/geoffrey-james/linkedin-vs-facebook-which-will-survive.html) and scroll to the bottom where the Facebook Comments should load. As a user, is there anything I can do to make these comments appear normally, short of resizing the default text in Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: I really want to know the answer to this as well!